# how to set two variables for a for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set two variables in a `for` loop in JavaScript.

```
function onOpen(cf) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 4;
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


//for (var n in ss.getSheets()){ {

for (var ree = startRow,  n in ss.getSheets(); ree <= numRows; ree++){ {

var rangeToCheck = sheet1.getRange(ree, 1);//  column D in row ree

var accesslist = sheet1.getRange(ree,2);
var namee = rangeToCheck.getValue();
var folder =  DriveApp.createFolder(namee);
```

This doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know any alternatives?

Comment: could you explain what exactly are you trying to do cause i'm a bit lost? Usually you can declare the variable inside the for loop itself if that is what you are getting at

Comment: n=ss.getSheets().keys()[ree] ?

Comment: What do you want with n and ree? Its quite broad at the moment..? As n in ss.getSheets() is in the declaration part, in is parsed as a declaration: n in ss.getSheets() => false ...

Comment: I want to loop for two conditions. I have modified the script above

Comment: @Jonasw I want to loop for two conditions

Comment: Its still not clear, why not two for loops?

Comment: @Jonasw the objective of the is to create folders for a spreadsheet  and move a tab to the new folder. If I create two loops, it is creating multiple folders for the same row.

Comment: ok, so then whats the relationship between n and ree?

Comment: @Jonasw n = the tab and ree is the folder . sheet 1 needs to go into folder 1 and sheet 2 has to go into folder 2 and the names of the folders is ree.

Comment: is getSheets() an array or an object?

Comment: @Jonasw its an array because it google app script function is to get all tabs from a particular sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just need one variable, because they are proportional:

```
var sssheets=ss.getSheets();//performance improvement
var ssoffset=0;// i think its -1 in your examples  
for(var ree=1;ree<=numRows && ree-ssoffset<sssheets.length; ree++){
     var sheet = sssheets[ree-ssofset];
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much :) that did the job